# Convergence of convex compact bodies implies Hausdorff convergence

Tags: real-analysis, gn.general-topology, convex-geometry, convexity

I am wondering about the following :

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, suppose you are given compact convex bodies $\left\{ C_k : k \geq 1 \right\}$ and $C$, such that:

- (simple convergence) for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $ \mathbb{1}_{C_k}(x) \rightarrow \mathbb{1}_C(x)$.
- ($L^1$ convergence) and one has $\lim ||\mathbb{1}_{C_k} -\mathbb{1}_C \||_1  = 0 $.

Is it true that the convex bodies $C_k$ converges to $C$ in the Hausdorff metric ? *i.e.* do we have, for any $\epsilon > 0$, a rank $k_0 \gg 1$ such that for any $k \geq k_0$, $C_k$ is included in the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $C$ and conversely ?

Comment: Without a uniform lower bound on the measure of a body it's obviously false. Imagine a clock with a convex arrow which thins over time, but does not get shorter. The arrow converges to its axis in measure, and if you take irrational angle of rotation and make it thin fast enough, it also converges pointwise.

Comment: Even a lower bound on the measure is not enough (take your clock example, but also elongate the arrows inversely to their thinness).  Having a lower bound on the measure *and* a uniform upper bound on diameter (i.e., restricting the John ellipsoid to a compact subspace of the set of all ellipsoids) would suffice though (basically, if $C_k$ pokes too far outside of $C$, or avoids a point too deep inside $C$, this will create a notable $L^1$ discrepancy between $1_C$ and $1_{C_k}$ via convexity of $C_k$).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments ! I am not really sure what is this clock counter example (how can you keep your arrow convex if you don't make it shorter ?) and I am not really sure how you can escape a point inside C.. but thanks for the suggestions I'll think about it !